# Automating Data Changes Between MSSqlServer and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, migration, transfer

So I've recently ported over a bunch of very large databases from SQL Server to MySQL using the migration wizard. This was done manually and was very time consuming. My next step is to automate this process in some way. As the databases that are a part of MSSqlServer are constantly being updated, I need to track these changes in MySQL as well in a short amount of time. My problem is that through the migration wizard, it takes many days to port all the data over. If there is one small change, it would be beneficial to simply track the change and change it in MySQL rather than reporting the entire database every week or so.

There's a few routes I thought of but I'm not sure if these will work or if they're practical or not.

1. Convert the migrations into scripts and run these scripts every week. This would allow me a route into automating the process. The problem however, is that it would take several days to retransfer all the data so it's not very practical.
2. Somehow link MySQL to MSSQLServer and track changes live on MySQL. I don't know if this is possible but it seems like it would be the most practical way to do this.

Any suggestions or help on solving this problem would be appreciated.

TL;DR: I need to track small changes in data from a MSSQLServer database to MySQL database without having to retransfer all the data via the migration wizard each time.

Comment: I would look into linked servers (from SQL Server to MySQL) and the facilities they provide.

Comment: You should look for any CDC tools to achieve this.